# angular-google-maps center zoom multiple markers

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, cordova-3, angular-google-maps

I'm using [AngularJS for Google Maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) and want to dynamically center and zoom a map based on multiple markers that are dynamically loaded. This is for a [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) app using the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/).

Here's my view:

```
<ion-view title="" ng-controller="MapCtrl as vm">
 <ion-content class="padding">
  <google-map id="mainMap" control="vm.googleMap" draggable="true" center="vm.map.center" zoom="vm.map.zoom" mark-click="false">
      <markers idKey="mainMap" fit="vm.map.fit">
          <marker idKey="marker.id" ng-repeat="marker in vm.map.markers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options">
              <marker-label content="marker.name" anchor="2 0" class="marker-labels"/>
          </marker>
      </markers>
  </google-map>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
 var vm = this;
 vm.googleMap = {}; // this is filled when google map is initialized, but it's too late
 vm.mapMarkers = [];

 vm.arrMarkers = [
    {
        id: "home",
        name: "home",
        coords: {
            latitude:xxxxxxx, //valid coords
            longitude:xxxxxxx //valid coords
        },
        options: {
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        }
    },
    {
        id: "placeAId",
        name: "Place A",
        coords: {
            latitude:xxxxxxx, //valid coords
            longitude:xxxxxxx //valid coords
        }
    },
    {
        id: "placeBId",
        name: "Place B",
        coords: {
            latitude:xxxxxxx, //valid coords
            longitude:xxxxxxx //valid coords
        }
    }
];
vm.map = {
    center: { //how to determine where to center???
        latitude: xxxxxxx, //valid coords
        longitude: xxxxxxx //valid coords
    },
    zoom: 12, //how to determine zoom dynamically???
    fit: true,
    markers: vm.arrMarkers
};

var setMapBounds = function () {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    createMarkers();
    var markers = vm.mapMarkers;
    for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
    }
    var map = vm.googleMap.control.getGMap();
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    //remove one zoom level to ensure no marker is on the edge.
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);

    // set a minimum zoom
    // if you got only 1 marker or all markers are on the same address map will be zoomed too much.
    if(map.getZoom()> 15){
        map.setZoom(15);
    }
};

var createMarkers = function() {
    var map = vm.googleMap.control.getGMap(); //vm.googleMap.control is undefined because this fire before map is initialized
    angular.forEach(vm.restaurants, function(restaurant, index) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(restaurant.coords.latitude, restaurant.coords.longitude),
            title: restaurant.name
        });
        vm.mapMarkers.push(marker);
    });
};

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    setMapBounds();
});
```

})

So, my question is how do I center and zoom the map using multiple dynamically loaded markers? Also, how do I get an instance of googleMap.control (vm.googleMap.control) before the map is loaded?

Comment: you should probably look at the demo code and API docs more. Most of the conventional gmap code you have is already built into the directive. Directive seems to use an unusual convention of needing to wrap variables in single quotes within markup

Comment: The online docs seem to be out of date and I've been going through the example demo code but can't find anything. Can you point me to a code snippet in the example code that might help?

Comment: have been through a bit of same frustration just recently. They did improve the docs quite a bit from when I started using them a few months ago.  `fit` in `<markers>` will manage `setMapBounds`. Create a demo in plunker, with a few data points and will try to help out. I have a project that I keep tweaking same thing that is currently ongoing

Comment: Thanks, but I am going to wait until AngularJS for Google Maps is more mature. I recently update the Ionic framework and now my map has disappeared entirely. Also, I didn't like the added dependency on lodash.underscore.js anyways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my code just in case anyone was wondering how to do this locally. This is a simple solution for what I needed and my indeed go back to angualr-google maps, but as  of now this works fine in my application.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.googleMap = null; 
    vm.mapMarkers = [];

    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        vm.userLocation.coords.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        vm.userLocation.coords.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        initializeMap();
    };

    var onError = function(error) {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message);
    };

    vm.userLocation = {
        id: "home",
        title: "home",
        coords: {
            latitude: 33.636727,
            longitude: -83.920702
        },
        options: {
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        }
    };

    vm.places = [
        {
            id: "78869C43-C694-40A5-97A0-5E709AA6CE51",
            title: "Place A",
            coords: {
                latitude: 33.625296,
                longitude: -83.976206
            }
        },
        {
            id: "52319278-83AA-46D4-ABA6-307EAF820E77",
            title: "Place B",
            coords: {
                latitude: 33.576522,
                longitude: -83.964981
            }
        }
    ];

    var addMarkers = function() {
        var userLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: vm.googleMap,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(vm.userLocation.coords.latitude, vm.userLocation.coords.longitude),
            //animation: vm.userLocation.options.animation,
            title: vm.userLocation.title
        });

        vm.mapMarkers.push(userLocation);

        angular.forEach(vm.places, function(location, index) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: vm.googleMap,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude),
                title: location.title
            });
            vm.mapMarkers.push(marker);
        });

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i = 0; i < vm.mapMarkers.length; i++) {
            bounds.extend(vm.mapMarkers[i].getPosition());
        }
        vm.googleMap.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        vm.googleMap.fitBounds(bounds);
        //remove one zoom level to ensure no marker is on the edge.
        vm.googleMap.setZoom(vm.googleMap.getZoom() - 1);

        // set a minimum zoom
        // if you got only 1 marker or all markers are on the same address map will be zoomed too much.
        if (vm.googleMap.getZoom() > 15) {
            vm.googleMap.setZoom(15);
        }
    };

    var initializeMap = function() {
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(vm.userLocation.coords.latitude, vm.userLocation.coords.longitude)
        };
        var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        //var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div, mapOptions);
        vm.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(div, mapOptions);
        addMarkers();

        var width = screen.width;
        var height = screen.height;
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

})
```

Answer (score 6):

Your previous answer is good but doesn't include usage of the google maps directives you mentioned in the begining of the post. There is a way to do it using those directives, here is how:

Assuming we are in the directive's scope

1. Define `scope.mapControl = {};` - this will have new access methods for map and markers
2. When defining your markup for the directives - for map and marker - include this control attribute to be added:

   ```
   <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'    control="mapControl">
       <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="location in locations" coords="location.coordinates" options="location.markerOptions" idkey="location.id" control="mapControl">
           <ui-gmap-window options="location.markerWindowOptions" closeclick="closeMarkerWindow(location.id)" show="true">
               <div>{{location.description}}</div>
           </ui-gmap-window>
       </ui-gmap-marker>
   </ui-gmap-google-map>
   ```
3. In your directive's event or some method:

   ```
   var map = scope.mapControl.getGMap();
   var markers = scope.mapControl.getGMarkers();
   var bounds = map.getBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
   }
   map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
   ```

Comment: I think this is much better solution, because it properly uses angulars architecture - data are bind to the the model and you care only about keeping your model correct - the view is rendered automatically